# Parse leading XML comment

Tags: xml, go, comments

I'd like to handle a configuration file. This file should be read and write by the application. The configuration file should contain comments to provide information about the configuration tags.

The comments inside the tags is no problem. I use the `'xml:",comment"'` tags.
But I cannot get the comments outside the `<ServerConfig>` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This is a comment I cannot get -->
<ServerConfig>
  <!-- This is a comment I can get -->
  <KeyStore>/tmp/test</KeyStore>
</ServerConfig>
```

I am able to parse the comment inside the `ServerConfig` tag using

```
type ServerConfig struct {
   Comment string `xml:",comment"`
   KeyStore string
}
```

How can I `Unmarshal()` the leading comment?

Comment: Note that both the xml and the Go code you've provided are invalid. The xml's missing a proper closing tag and the Go code is using `'` as a tag delimiter which is illegal.

Comment: You could not parse comments outside of XML Base tag, Decoder loads tags from init tag.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/DbkKHlU-lTP

Comment: Adapt the xml and Go code to be correct, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xml.NewDecoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#NewDecoder) to read the `xml` line-by-line and implement custom parsing algorithm

```
const configXml =`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This is a comment I cannot get -->
<ServerConfig>
  <!-- This is a comment I can get -->
  <KeyStore>/tmp/test</KeyStore>
</ServerConfig>`
```

```
dec := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(configXml))
for{
    tok, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        panic(err)
    } else if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if tok == nil {
        fmt.Println("token is nil")
    }
    switch toke := tok.(type) {
    case xml.Comment:
        fmt.Println(string(toke))
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5yFQSu_lnFL)

```
 This is a comment I cannot get 
 This is a comment I can get
```